# Как получить переменную из массива?

Tags: веб-программирование, angularjs

Заполняю массив данными:

```
for(i=1;i<=46;i++){
    $scope.Pagin_array.push(i);
}
```

Вывожу его:

```
<li ng-click="Pagination();" ng-repeat="x in Pagin_array ">{{x}}</li>
```

Обработчик ng-click:

```
$scope.Pagination = function(){
alert($scope.Pagin_array);
}
```

Вывод (запятые для наглядности):

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9...46
```

Я хочу получить число по клику на него. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого его нужно передать в качестве параметра:

```
<li ng-click="Pagination(x);" ng-repeat="x in Pagin_array ">{{x}}</li>
```

В коде соответственно:

```
$scope.Pagination = function(x){
    alert(x);
}
```

Comment: Благодарю! Совсем уже запутался :)